# How to weigh a function with 2 variables with a Gaussian distribution in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, probability-theory

I've been working with this for the last days and I couldn't see yet where is the problem.

I'm trying to weight a function with 2 variables `f(q,r)` within a Gaussian distribution `g(r)` with a specific mean value (`R0`) and deviation (`sigma`). This is needed because the theoretical function `f(q)` has a certain dispersity in its `r` variable when analyzed experimentally. Therefore, we use a probability density function to weigh our function in the `r` variable.

I include the code, which works, but doesn't give the expected result (the weighted curve should be smoother as the polydispersity grows (higher `sigma`) as it is shown below. As you can see, I integrated the convolution of the 2 functions `f(r,q)*g(r)` from `r = 0` to `r = +inf`.

[image: DIFFERENT POLYDISPERSITIES]

The result is plotted to compare the weigh result with the simple function:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad, quadrature
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#function weighted with a probability density function (gaussian)
def integrand(r,q):
    #gaussian function normalized
    def gauss_nor(r):
        #gaussian function
        def gauss(r):
            return m.exp(-((r-R0)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
        return (m.exp(-((r-R0)**2)/(2*sigma**2)))/(quad(gauss,0,np.inf)[0])
    #function f(r,q)
    def f(r,q):
        return 3*(np.sin(q*r)-q*r*np.cos(q*r))/((r*q)**3)
    return gauss_nor(r)*f(r,q)

#quadratic integration of the integrand (from 0 to +inf)
#integrand is function*density_function (gauss) 
def function(q):
    return quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=(q))[0]

#parameters used in the function
R0=20
sigma=5

#range to plot q
q=np.arange(0.001,2.0,0.005)

#vector where the result of the integral will be saved
function_vec = np.vectorize(function)

#vector for the squared power of the integral
I=[]
I=(function_vec(q))**2

#function without density function
I0=[]
I0=(3*(np.sin(q*R0)-q*R0*np.cos(q*R0))/((R0*q)**3))**2

#plot of weighted and non-weighted functions
p1,=plt.plot(q,I,'b')
p3,=plt.plot(q,I0,'r')
plt.legend([p1,p3],('Weighted','No weighted'))
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much. I've been with this problems for some days already and I haven't found the mistake.

Maybe somebody know how to weigh a function with a PDF in an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code, the output is the same as yours. I think it's already very smooth, there are some very sharp peak in the log-log graph, just because the curve has zero points. So it's not smooth in a log-log graph, but it's smooth in a normal X-Y graph.

```
import numpy as np

def gauss(r):
    return np.exp(-((r-R0)**2)/(2*sigma**2))

def f(r,q):
    return 3*(np.sin(q*r)-q*r*np.cos(q*r))/((r*q)**3)

R0=20
sigma=5

qm, rm = np.ogrid[0.001:2.0:0.005, 0.001:40:1000j]
gr = gauss(rm)
gr /= np.sum(gr)
fm = f(rm, qm)
fm *= gr

plot(qm.ravel(), fm.sum(axis=1)**2)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. This was waaay simpler and the results are still the same. However, though the code works, it doesn´t give the expected results, which I just uploaded in my question with a graph. I hope it helps understanding the question...

Comment: @Gauson these plots look very similar to me... note your example has a linear axis and HYRY's answer is plotted on a log axis.  At a second look these cusps are at `x<1` and yours are `x>1`

Comment: Thank you very much! The code was correct from the beginning, but what HYRY posted has been very helpful for further weighted functions. The problem had been all the time that I was making the power of the weighted function and not weighing the power of the function. Important to keep on mind: Always weigh at the end ;)